# Using Nested Keys as Values in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am trying to map English descriptions to the nested elements that I will need to access from a dictionary so I can present the data in an English readable format. For example I will print something like:

```
for k,v in A_FIELDS.iteritems()

    print k + "= " resultsDict[v]
```

For every k,v in the A_FIELDS Dict below.

```
A_FIELDS = {
        'Total Requests'    :   "['requests']['all']",
        'Cached Requests'   :   "['requests']['cached']",
        'Uncached Requests' :   "['requests']['uncached']",
        'Total Bandwidth'   :   "['bandwidth']['all']",
        'Cached Bandwidth'  :   "['bandwidth']['cached']",
        'Uncached Bandwidth':   "['bandwidth']['uncached']",
        'Total Page View'   :   "['pageviews']['all']",
        'Total Uniques'     :   "['uniques']['all']"
    }
```

However, regardless of the way I'm formatting the dictionary, I get one of two errors. I've tried " " around the values with no inner quotes (keyError) and only inner quotes (list indices must be integers not str).

Any idea how I can use the values to access a dictionary and print the keys so it's english readable? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. Instead of repeatedly using the terms "key" and "value," you could clarify the task you're trying to complete by explaining what you're actually hoping to do, with sample input/output.

Comment: Fair enough. I've tried to make it clearer. I'm mapping english words to values in a dictionary.

Comment: What do you want it to print out?  You've got an odd string-inside-list-inside-string thing going on.  Like, if I try `A_FIELDS['Total Uniques']` what should it be printing?

Comment: I'm trying to print a label (Total Uniques) by accessing a dictionary with a key of ['uniques']['all']. I'm trying to map human readable labels (Total Uniques) with the actual values, which are found in a dictionary and located at ['uniques']['all']. Sorry if this was not clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store each key in a `list`.

```
resultsDict = {'requests':{'all':0, 'cached':1, 'uncached':2},
'bandwidth':{'all':0, 'cached':1, 'uncached':2},
'pageviews':{'all':0, 'cached':1, 'uncached':2},
'uniques':{'all':0, 'cached':1, 'uncached':2}}

A_FIELDS = {
        'Total Requests'    :   ['requests', 'all'],
        'Cached Requests'   :   ['requests', 'cached'],
        'Uncached Requests' :   ['requests', 'uncached'],
        'Total Bandwidth'   :   ['bandwidth', 'all'],
        'Cached Bandwidth'  :   ['bandwidth', 'cached'],
        'Uncached Bandwidth':   ['bandwidth', 'uncached'],
        'Total Page View'   :   ['pageviews', 'all'],
        'Total Uniques'     :   ['uniques', 'all']
    }
```

If you are always accessing two levels (e.g. `'requests'` then `'all'`), simply unpack the keys:

```
>>> for k,(v1,v2) in A_FIELDS.iteritems():
...     print '{} = {}'.format(k, resultsDict[v1][v2])
...
Total Page View = 0
Cached Bandwidth = 1
Uncached Requests = 2
Total Uniques = 0
Total Bandwidth = 0
Uncached Bandwidth = 2
Total Requests = 0
Cached Requests = 1
```

If you will be accessing to an arbitrary depth, use a loop:

```
>>> for k,v in A_FIELDS.iteritems():
...     result = resultsDict
...     for key in v:
...         result = result[key]
...     print '{} = {}'.format(k, result)
...
Total Page View = 0
Cached Bandwidth = 1
Uncached Requests = 2
Total Uniques = 0
Total Bandwidth = 0
Uncached Bandwidth = 2
Total Requests = 0
Cached Requests = 1
```